Vue.JS DeprecationWarning: The `util._extend` API is deprecated. Please use Object.assign() instead
Whilst executing a call API request, the Vue.JS application throws an error. API is running at Okta, and the request is successful through cURL in CLI.
Error thrown
(node:82171) [DEP0060] DeprecationWarning: The `util._extend` API is deprecated. Please use Object.assign() instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
7:45:24 PM [vite] http proxy error:

ExternalAPI.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="mb-5">
      <h1>External API</h1>
      <p>
        Call an external API by clicking the button below. This will call the
        external API using an access token, and the API will validate it using
        the API's audience value.
      </p>

      <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5" @click="callApi">Call API</button>
    </div>

    <div class="result-block-container">
      <div :class="['result-block', apiMessage ? 'show' : '']">
        <h6 class="muted">Result</h6>
        <highlightjs language="json" :code="JSON.stringify(apiMessage, null, 2) || ''" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "api-view",
  setup() {
    const auth0 = useAuth0();
    const apiMessage = ref();

    return {
      apiMessage,
      async callApi() {
        // Get the access token from Auth0
        const accessToken = await auth0.getAccessTokenSilently();

        try {
          // Call the external API with the access token
          const response = await fetch("/api/external", {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
          });

          // Parse the response as JSON
          const data = await response.json();

          // Store the API response in the apiMessage variable
          apiMessage.value = data;
        } catch (e: any) {
          // Handle any errors that occur during the API call
          apiMessage.value = `Error: the server responded with '${e.response.status}: ${e.response.statusText}'`;
        }
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>

Viteconfig.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:3001',
    }
  },
  plugins: [vue()]
})

I tried to update the packages with npm and locate where the util.\_extend (API) is being used. Nowhere in the files is this line mentioned, it may be in an imported library that I am using.
Running the application with trace deprecation leads me to this
**NODE_OPTIONS=--trace-deprecation npm run serve**
(node:84741) [DEP0060] DeprecationWarning: The `util.\_extend` API is deprecated. Please use Object.assign() instead.
    at ProxyServer.<anonymous> (/Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:56939:26)
    at viteProxyMiddleware (/Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:57226:23)
    at call (/Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:44131:7)
    at next (/Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:44075:5)
    at cors (/Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:44599:7)
    at /Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:44635:17
    at originCallback (/Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:44625:15)
    at /Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:44630:13
    at optionsCallback (/Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:44610:9)
    at corsMiddleware (/Users/rami-dev/Documents/Pizza42Okta/02-Calling-an-API/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0a035c79.js:44615:7)
8:03:38 PM [vite] http proxy error: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]:
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1117:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1684:7)


TL;DR - upgrade vite to latest version. I just looked it up, that warning was fixed a month ago - not sure when that change made it to the release version of vite, but it's been a while since I've seen that warning.

I'm having a similar error message using Nodejs to run a static website.

Apparently, this is a Node.js error. Try to get down to version 20 of Node.js.

@ramonz000 if this has answered your question, you can mark it
